# AngularJS: Prevent backspace on modal box

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am working on angular application. Where a user opens a modal box, the focus will be on first textbox. Like this

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <b></b>
         <div><b>First Name</b></div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" style="width:150px" focus="true" name="firstName" ng-model="record.firstName"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <b></b>
         <div><b>Last Name</b></div>
      </td>
      <td><input focus type="text" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" style="width:150px" name="lastName" ng-model="record.lastName"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <b></b>
         <div><b>Title</b></div>
      </td>
      <td><input focus type="text" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" style="width:150px" name="title" ng-model="record.title"></td>
   </tr>  
   <tr>
      <td>
         <b></b>
         <div><b>Language</b></div>
      </td>
      <td><input focus type="text" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" style="width:150px" name="language" ng-model="record.language"></td>
   </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Thsi is the directive for focus

```
directives.directive('focus',function($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope : {
                    trigger : '@focus'
                },
                link : function(scope, element) {
                    var focusables = $(":focusable");
                    scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
                        if (value === "true") {
                            $timeout(function() {
                                element[0].focus();
                            });
                        }
                    });
                element.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code === 13) {
                    var current = focusables.index(this);
                    var next = focusables.eq(current + 1).length ? focusables.eq(current + 1) : focusables.eq(0);
                    next.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
              });
            }
        };
    });
```

When a user open the modal box and clicks on outside the textbox or modal box focus will be disappeared and when he click on backspace modal box will be there but the backside page is redirecting to previous page. 
How to prevent backspace here. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding `keydown` on element, bind it on the document or the body.

Instead of:

```
element.bind('keydown', function(e) {
```

try:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {...});
```

**JS:**

```
element.parents("body").bind('keydown', function (e) {
     //Condition to check if modal is opened
     var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
     if (code === 13) {
         var current = focusables.index(this);
         var next = focusables.eq(current + 1).length ? focusables.eq(current + 1) : focusables.eq(0);
         next.focus();
         e.preventDefault();
     }
 });
```

And, make sure you place a condition inside the event handler to check whether the modal is opened or not. You want to prevent the backspace navigation only if the modal is opened. So, you'll need to apply this only when modal is opened.

Comment: @K K thanks for reply. Can you please give an example. I have tried lot of methods but I am not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer:

```
directives.directive('disablebackbtn',function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (!attrs.modalVisible)
            {
                console.log("********************Modal Opened");
                element.parents("body").bind('keydown', function (e) {
                    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    var nodeName = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                    if (e.which === 8) {
                        if ((nodeName === 'input' && e.target.type === 'text') ||
                            nodeName === 'textarea') {
                            // do nothing
                        } else {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

    }
};
});
```